# GridNodeShadow removed from GridDiscoveryEvent?

Tags: gridgain

When attempting to upgrade to GridGain 6.1.6, I noticed that the shadow() accessor has been removed from the GridDiscoveryEvent.

What's the reason and recommended workaround ? Should I be using the discoveryEvent.node() method instead ?

Thanks

```
    GridDiscoveryEvent discoveryEvent = (GridDiscoveryEvent) event;
    GridNodeShadow shadow = discoveryEvent.shadow(); //=====> .shadow() not valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be eventNode(), since that is what the shadow() was backed by, in the old source code.

Thanks

Comment: Yup, GridDiscoveryEvent.eventNode()